# TPicture Width and Height reported incorrectly for .ico files (Delphi 7)

Tags: image, delphi, icons, delphi-7

Using Delphi 7. I have a simple routine successfully loading `.bmp`, `.emf`, `.wmf`, `.ico` and `.jpg` files (code given below). My problem is that every `.ico` (Icon) file always reports `TImage.TPicture.Width` and `TImage.TPicture.Height` as "32". All icons are 32-bit with a single page inside. It doesn't matter what the actual size is (I have tried 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 and 128x128).

If I manually set `TImage.Width` and `TImage.Width` to what I *know* the icon size is, the image displays nicely. All the other file types report the size correctly.

Why is there a problem with `.ico` files and how do I correct or workaround the problem.

```
procedure TfrmImageLoader.btnBrowseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    openPictureDlg: TOpenPictureDialog;
    jpgImage: TJPEGImage;
    testWidth, testHeight: Integer;
begin
    // Browse for the image file
    openPictureDlg := TOpenPictureDialog.Create(Self);
    if (openPictureDlg.Execute) then
        begin
        // Check if file exists
        if (FileExists(openPictureDlg.FileName)) then
            begin
            // Load the image into out image component
            imgLoaded.Visible := False;
            if (IsJPEG(openPictureDlg.FileName)) then
                begin
                jpgImage := TJPEGImage.Create();
                jpgImage.LoadFromFile(openPictureDlg.FileName);
                imgLoaded.Picture.Assign(jpgImage);
                jpgImage.Free();
                end
            else
                begin
                imgLoaded.Picture.LoadFromFile(openPictureDlg.FileName);
                end;
                
            // Test width...here's the problem. Icons always report "32".
            testWidth := m_imgLoaded.Picture.Width;
            testHeight := m_imgLoaded.Picture.Height;
            m_imgLoaded.Visible := True;
            end
        else
            begin
            // File does not exist
            MessageDlg('File does not exist', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
            end;
        end;

    // Clean up
    openPictureDlg.Free();
end;
```

#### Update 1

As a test, I loaded the file as a `TIcon`, but the results are the same.

```
ico: TIcon;
// ...
ico := TIcon.Create();
ico.LoadFromFile(openPictureDlg.FileName);
testWidth := ico.Width;   // Still 32, regardless of the actual size
testHeight := ico.Height;
ico.Free();
```

#### Update 2

See the accepted answer. There are basically two ways to get the correct size (a) load the icon, assign to a TBitmap, and read the bitmap size or (b) read the icon header, bytes 7 & 8 are the width/height. The latter is ~20 times faster in my tests and the code is given below:

```
procedure GetTrueIconSize2(const cszIcon: String; var trueW: Integer; var trueH: Integer);
var
    fs: TFileStream;
    firstBytes: AnsiString;
begin
    // The size of image/vnd.microsoft.icon MIME files (Windows icon) is in the header
    // at bytes 7 & 8. A value of "0" means "256" (the largest icon size supported).
    fs := TFileStream.Create(cszIcon, fmOpenRead);
    try
        SetLength(firstBytes, 8);
        fs.Read(firstBytes[1], 8);
        trueW := Integer(firstBytes[7]);
        if (trueW = 0) then
            trueW := 256;

        trueH := Integer(firstBytes[8]);
        if (trueH  = 0) then
            trueH := 256;
    finally
        fs.Free();
    end;
end;
```

Comment: (I trust that you would use `try..finally` to protect your objects in a real application.)

Comment: Yes, just stripped out some code for minimal sample! :o)

Comment: Alain: Good! :)

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce the problem in Delphi 10.3.2 using [a simple 48×48 px icon](http://privat.rejbrand.se/test.ico).

Comment: BTW, Delphi 7 was released almost 18 years ago. Time to upgrade?

Comment: You're right of course and the latest Delphi is awesome! Its some legacy code I'm playing with. I've discovered this article http://www.delphigroups.info/2/11/316642.html which has a method to find out the true size of an icon (see the response from Chris Willing on 2006-03-14). Just testing it on 128x128 and 16x16 icons and it works, so for now I'll adapt that the project, but upgrading would simplify things...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Thanks for testing in Delphi 10.3.2 and confirming the issue is resolved, BTW.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to single out JPG files. `TPicture.LoadFromFile()` will use `TJPEGImage` internally when loading a JPG filename.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You're right! Good spot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to parse ICO files yourself, which is rather trivial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format) - that way you easily know the dimensions for each entry. In the most simple case (only one picture) the first 6 bytes of the file must be `#0#0#1#0#1#0` and byte 7 and 8 are width and height.

Comment: Great, thanks! Learnt something new that since 1 byte is reserved for the image/width, icon dimensions are limited to 256x256 (0 means `256`). Will check out that article and try it out, thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to present me an ICO that has larger dimensions than 256x256.

Comment: Works nicely! Simply read the first eight bytes with `TFileStream`. The 7th and 8th bytes are the Width and Height respectively (0 means 256).